# REST API or what?

Tags: php, api, rest, titanium

I'm developing a mobile application using Titanium Studio and the server side is written in PHP. I want the app to get data from the server and display them to the user?

What approach is good for this case? I'm thinking of using a REST API, however the app will display data before the user has logged in, only certain parts are required to login first. How I want it to behave:

- Fetch data from the server via the client app I've built only, no other access possible
- Login the user through the app client -> server. How do I do this using an API?
- The API isn't public to everyone, just the app I've built.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your points:

(1) A REST API which returns JSON/XML etc can be used by your client app. If you want to restrict access to the REST service to your mobile clients only, then an authentication token can be passed with the client requests

(2) Same as above, you can have a login method to validate the user, and then return an authentication token which may be used while requesting subscription/secure data

(3) Unless you have made the API/URI public it is not known to others. And this is where you can pass a GUID token or reference string from the client to the service and the service will know the requests are coming from your clients.

Hope this answers your questions.

Comment: Thank you. Is oAuth necessary to accomplish this, or should I come up with something different?

Comment: @Glend: OAuth is a possible solution, but if it's for a single application with a non-public API, it's probably not necessary. For item 2, a minimal solution would be to (after successfully checking the credentials) sign a message containing some user identifier and an expiry time and send that signed message back to the client. To verify it, just verify the signature and check that it has not expired. To see who it was issued to, unwrap the message and extract the user identifier.